# Why my PathSegment is null while @PathParam is not null?

Tags: jax-rs, path-parameter

With following code, `serviceIdSegment` is `null` while `serviceId` is not `null`.

```
class MySubResource {

    @GET
    @Path("{serviceId: .+}")
    public Response readById(@PathParam String serviceId) {
        // serviceId is not null
        // why serviceIdSegment is null?
    }

    @PathParam("serviceId");
    private PathSegment serviceIdSegment;
}
```

Can anybody please tell me why?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed, when I tried to answer, that this question is mine.

The `readById` method is lazily evaluated after the root resource class is matched.